# Update with limit and offset applied to joined table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN. My overall question is how (if it is possible at all) to set LIMIT and OFFSET to that joined table.

Example query without limit and offset:

```
UPDATE t2 
SET t2.some_col = t1.some_col
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
ON t1.other_col = t2.other_col
```

And how to rebuild this query to get only first 1000000, 1000000 - 2000000, 2000000 - 3000000, ... etc. records from t2.

Exact scenery:

My task is to rebuild very large tables with hash indexes (char(32)) to bigint indexes. Example tables:

```
URLS:                               PAGE_VIEWS:
id char(32)                         urlId char(32) 
other_columns                       referrerUrlId char(32) 
intUrlId bigint (added and filled)  other_columns 
                                    intUrlId bigint (needs to update)
                                    intReferrerUrlId bigint (needs to update)
```

First table is about 200 mln records, second over 1 bln. I update this tables in packs. The update job wouldn't be difficult if I could use WHERE urls.intUrlId BETWEEN ... but I can't. Sometimes JOIN return on example 500000 records for single pack but many times it returns 0 so it update 0 records but join in such big tables costs quite a lot of time. So I need equal packs limited by page_views table not urls table. Page_views table has no column I can base WHERE clause so I need limit this table by TOP and ROW_NUMBER() clauses but I dunno how. (I'm quite new in MsSQL, I used to work on MySQL and PostgreSql databases which has LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.

For any answer I would appreciate info about cost of this solution because someone would appreciate any LIMIT - OFFSET solution but not me. I already have query which update what I need. But it use intUrlId from urls table and it is slow. I need faster solution. Server version 2008.

BTW. Don't ask me who the hell based database on char indexes :-) Now it become a problem and multi TBs database needs to be rebuilded.

Comment: Connections are not clear.  You have table_1, table_2, URLS, and PAGE_VIEWS.  Then refer to first table.   The question is not clear.  Don't assume the solution is LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: I can clarify what is needed but I don't know what is unclear to you in my question. Connections? There are 2 tables URLS and PAGE_VIEWS and I join on example them by 'ON urls.id = page_views.urlId'. Exact query is:
UPDATE pv

  SET pv.intUrlId = urls.intUrlId

  FROM [XXX].[ZZZ].[Urls] urls WITH(NOLOCK)

  INNER JOIN [XXX].[YYY].[PageViews] pv WITH(NOLOCK)

  ON pv.urlId = urls.id

  And I need to create packs by limiting records returned from join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question "how to set LIMIT, OFFSET to joined table" in Jeremy's answer tables needs to be switched. I'll give correct answer for example query I used in my question.

```
WITH toUpdate AS
(
   SELECT some_col, other_col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY any_column) AS RowNumber
   FROM table_2
) 
UPDATE toUpdate 
SET toUpdate.some_col = t1.some_col 
FROM table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN toUpdate ON t1.other_col = toUpdate.other_col
AND RowNumber BETWEEN 1000000 AND 2000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a CTE with a RowNumber

```
    WITH toUpdate AS
(
    SELECT urlId, intUrlId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS RowNumber
    FROM [XXX].[ZZZ].[Urls] 
) 

UPDATE pv 
SET pv.intUrlId = urls.intUrlId 
FROM toUpdate urls
INNER JOIN [XXX].[YYY].[PageViews] pv WITH(NOLOCK) ON pv.urlId = urls.id and RowNumber between 10000 and 20000
```

Comment: It would be good if I had in t2 table any int column. Then without such combinations as you propose I could use WHERE clause directly in update query. But this is not the case.

Comment: Updated my answer understanding that ID is a CHAR not an INT

Comment: I'm not familiar with WITH clause so even I've found here similiar query for SELECT statement I wasn't sure how to use it for UPDATE. You helped me to understand how to use it in any query so +1. However I can't fully accept it because it doesn't answer my question - "how to set LIMIT, OFFSET to joined table in UPDATE query". Your anser is very close because switching tables doesn't change a lot but to not confuse future readers of this question I'll answer my own question and correct your answer

Comment: There was also tiny mistake in example query - join was ok but it should update t2 not t1. Maybe it mislead you a bit Jeremy - if so sorry for that.